# OpenNMS installation failure

Tags: tomcat, postgresql, network-monitoring, windows-xp, opennms

I am willing to use OpenNMS to monitor my network. Monitoring it fully from the router to the nodes from a computer will be connecting the network as node not as administrator and that computer using Windows XP SP3, with 1.5 GB RAM, 160 GB Hardisk and Intel premium processor.

So I read that OpenNMS requires JDK, PostgreSQL and Apache Tomcat, then I can install it. I'd done it all and I'm sure it's done correctly. When I try to access the web page using localhost, it doesn't work. I tried changing the IP to default software IP `127.0.0.1` and my own IP `192.168.1.151`, also tried ports `8980`, `5432`, `80` and `88`, but it still doesn't work.

Any suggestion would be helpful to me.

Comment: You should post an error message or the reuse of what happens when you try to access the OpenNMS page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're installing onto Windows XP.

Either way, your OpenNMS login page should be: `http://192.168.1.151:8980/opennms/login.jsp`

However, the OpenNMS mailing list would be a better resource for any questions beyond this.
http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Mailing_lists

Comment: is it costing problem when I use windows XP?

Comment: the reason am using it because its the only OS provided in the lab..

Answer (score 0):

I manged to run it already and its works well now.

the thing I missed is I didn't install any phpadmin and here I installed phpPgAdmin.
second thing I were having 2 version of Postgresql I deleted the oldest.
then its working now...

thanx for trying to help me @ewwhite